# Transfer Data to MySQL using Play framework

Tags: mysql, playframework, playframework-2.2

I have a Excel file with column structure as follows

> **FileCode  |  Period  | Release Date | Release Time**

And MySQL Database structure that looks like this

```
> Name | Country | Address |Release Date| Release Time| FileCode| Period
```

I don't know where to start looking for.
How can I insert bulk data in MySQL database using Play framework.

**Note**- I have java code that can read excel and convert its data into arrays I need to pass this to MySQL.  and I am using Play 2.2.2

Thanks,

Comment: Use [plain JDBC](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaDatabase), [Anorm](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaAnorm) or [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/) if you're using Scala. If you're using Java, use [plain JDBC](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaDatabase), [Ebean](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaEbean) or [JPA](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaJPA).

Comment: Yes.. I have found Ebean Module helpful. the documentation is here http://www.avaje.org/ebean/documentation.html If you are using Play than Ebean can simplify all your SQL related statements.